# Foreach loop in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Following code is fine to retrieve relevant result from DB. But when result is null, It shows

> **Notice**: Undefined variable: myArrayOfemp_id in Warning: Invalid
>   argument supplied for foreach() in .

```
$result1 = "SELECT leave_id FROM emp_leaves where duty_assign=".$userID;
$array = mysql_query($result1);
$cnt = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($array)) {
    $myArrayOfemp_id[$cnt] = $row[0];
    $cnt++;
}
// var_dump($myArrayOfemp_id);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM emp_leaves WHERE ";
foreach ($myArrayOfemp_id as $value)  {
    $sql .= " leave_id={$value} || ";
}
$sql .= "1=2";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

How can I avoid from displaying that error. Please help !

Comment: why this `sql .= "1=2";` ? it will always give emptyresult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize array  $myArrayOfemp_id before while loop

```
$myArrayOfemp_id = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($array)) {
      $myArrayOfemp_id[$cnt] = $row[0];
      $cnt++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you also should make sure to escape your strings before putting them in the query. see here for a better explanation [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement)

And before the while loop you should check with `mysql_num_rows()` if there are any results.

Comment: Let me know how can I give ORDER BY condition to query of in foreach

Comment: just do it after the last query string: `$sql .= "1=2";` Like this: `$sql .= " ORDER BY leave_id";

Comment: Thank u in advance for your answer,

Answer (score 1):

Hi First why you are using `"1=2"` it should be `1=1`. Second always define array before using it so define `$myArrayOfemp_id = array();` before while loop.

For sake of correct ouput please print  your `$sql` before executing is means.
 `echo $sql;` and run the resultant query in `Phpmyadmin`

Comment: I changed it as 1=1, Another thing is how can I give ORDER BY condition to query of in foreach

Comment: @Chathurika just  write this line $sql .= "1= 1 ORDER BY leave_id"    or    $sql .= "1= 1 ORDER BY leave_id DESC" according to your sorting order